# I'm trying to capture data in a web url with regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to build my regex to match my urls

Here are 2 example urls

category/sorganiser/bouger/escalade/offre/78934/
category/sorganiser/savourer/offre/8040/

I would like to get the number just after offre (78934 and 8040)
as well as the word just before the word offre (escalade and savourer)

I did several tests but did not pass

`^category/(((\w)+/){1,3})(\d+)/?$`

`^category/(((\w)+/){1,3})/offre/(\d+)/?$`

https://regex101.com/r/S4MTvK/1

Thank you

Comment: Try: `^category/\S*/([^/]+)/offre/(\d+)/?$`

Comment: Or with the quantifier, use an extra capture group after it `^category(?:/\w+){1,3}/(\w+)/offre/(\d+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of repeating a single word char in a group `(\w)+` you can repeat 1+ word chars in a single group `(\w+)`

**Note** to not match the `/` before `/offre` as it is already matched in the iteration `^category/(?:(\w+)/){1,3}`

---

You can repeat the capture group inside a non capture group `(?:` to capture the last occurrence in the iteration.

```
^category/(?:(\w+)/){1,3}offre/(\d+)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `category/` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(\w+)/` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars and match `/`
- `){1,3}` Close non capture, repeat 1-3 times and capture group 1 contains the last occurrence of 1+ word chars which is *escalade* or *savourer*
- `offre/` Match literally
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iaGQ4S/1)

To also match an optional `/` before the end of the sting

```
^category/(?:(\w+)/){1,3}offre/(\d+)/?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LyqrX/1)